# Block GUI when waiting for QTcpSocket data

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

I am writing a program to interact with a network-based API using Qt.
The interaction with the API is made with XML messages (both queries and results)

I implemented the communication and data processing in a class in a shared library project and I have a QMainWindow in which the user can enter the connection details. When clicking on the connect button, the following should happen:
 1. An instance of the connecting class is created.
 2. A connection message is sent to the API to get the session ID. The answer is parsed and a session ID is stored in the class instance.
 3. A message is sent to the API the get some field information. The XML is then parsed to extract the required field information to get data from the API.
 4. Another message is sent to get the data matching the fields. The XML answer is then parsed and stored in a data structure for processing.
 5. The data is then processed and finally displayed to the user.

I made a simple console program to test the library and it is working fine - no message is sent before all the data from the previous message has been processed. However, when I implement the same process in a QMainWindow instance, no wait occurs and messages are sent one after another without waiting.

How can I block the GUI thread to wait for full processing before sending the next message?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't block GUI thread. Revise your code to see on which event you're sending the next message. If it's appropriate move all tcp send/receive code to another thread.

Comment: I know that in general I should not block the GUI thread, but in this case I have to, because the data extracted need to be processed before rendering. I don't want the user to be able to interrupt the process.

Comment: And if he really needs to? Use popup dialog or block relevant GUI items individually. Just like all apps do.

Comment: Well, since the user will be mostly me (and maybe one or two other persons who sit next to me) and since it is an internal tool for the company I work for, well, I can tell you that there are very few chances the user will need to interrupt the program. Also, from the other tools developed and used here before I arrived, it seems to be a common practice to do it this way. I know it is not ideal, but at least the behavior will be consistent :(

Comment: The pattern is: block the UI somehow (disable it, etc.) and use the async APIs of QTcpSocket to get data. If you need to wait for more data, store the one you already have somewhere, and return to the event loop. Once you've got all the data process it and unblock the UI.

Comment: You can use local QEventLoop with ExcludeUserInputEvents set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking the UI isn't achieved by blocking the event loop. It's done by disabling the widgets that you don't want to allow interaction with - either by literally calling `disable()` method on them, or by guarding the interaction based on some state variable, e.g.:

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, button, [this]{
  if (! hasAllData) return;
  // react to a button press
});
```

All you need is to define a set of states your application can be in, and disable relevant widgets in appropriate states. I presume that once the session is established, it'd be fastest to issue all queries in parallel anyway, and asynchronously update the UI as the replies come back in real time.